# @config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx dependancy issue

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to installing this package to allow me to use react-native-ble-plx on expo app, yet I face dependency issue, can any one help please:

npx expo install

```
› Installing using npm
> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: expo-ble-sample@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: expo@48.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/expo
npm ERR!   expo@"~48.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer expo@"^47.0.3" from @config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx
npm ERR!   @config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/macbook/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbook/.npm/_logs/2023-03-03T13_38_55_583Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either downgrade the expo version itself, or you can open an issue on the package, or you can fork the library and upgrade the supported expo version on your own.